# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"contacts", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I know there are many people asking the same question but I simply cannot find the solution.

This error is happening when I attempt to edit a contact. Which means I need to query the DB for the current contact.

My edit method looks like this

```
def edit
    @contact = Contact.active
                      .select("phone_number, email, first_name, last_name, address1, address2, city, state, zipcode, country, gender, birthday, optional1, optional2, optional3, optional4, optional5, string_agg(tags.name,',') as tags")
                      .where("contacts.organization_id = ? and contacts.id = ?", current_users_user.organization_id, params[:id])
                      .joins("INNER JOIN tag_contacts on tag_contacts.contact_id = contacts.id")
                      .joins("INNER JOIN tags on tags.id = tag_contacts.tag_id")
                      .group("contacts.id,phone_number, email, first_name, last_name, address1, address2, city, state, zipcode, country, gender, birthday, optional1, optional2, optional3, optional4, optional5")
                      .first
end
```

When I click the edit button I receive this error.

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"contacts", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

But when I copy and paste the query from the terminal window to Postgres the query returns one record with exactly what I need.

this is my route for contacts

```
resources :contacts, :only => %w(index new edit show update create destroy) do
  get 'import', on: :collection 
  collection {post :exec_import}
end
```

Ask me any extra info that you may need! thank you so much!

**EDIT**

This is how I am calling it

```
<%= form_for @contact, url: contact_path(@contact) do |f| %>
```

and these are my routes!

[image]

EDIT 2

Logs! (This is what runs when you click the edit button)

[image]

Comment: Something's wrong with the edit link please post the code for edit link

Comment: @DeepakMahakale i added my routes and edit link

Answer (score 0):

The error you have posted is routing to `show` action and not to `edit` action.

Probably, you need to change the link to `edit` action and you need to pass contact ID in the edit contact link as below (assuming you have required contact in `@contact` variable) :

```
<%= link_to 'Edit contact', edit_contact_path(@contact.id) %>
```

Comment: all my other edits are done this way and they work.. Im not sure why it isn't working. your method gives me error too.

Comment: From your log I think value of `@contact` variable is `nil`. Check what value present in `@contact` variable in `edit` action by printing it in console as `p @contact`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the `url` Rails will figure out if the path is for creating or updating the record.

You must be using the same `_form` for `new` and `edit` actions.

```
<%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
```

Comment: I get a different error `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`

Comment: You should set it to `@contact = Contact.new` in new action and `@contact = Contact.find(params[:id])` in edit action

Comment: Can you please post the log also

Comment: Sees like there is something else which is causing the issue